# SMTP server to edit email content on the fly

Tags: email, smtp

I am looking for an open-source / free SMTP server that will enable me to automatically change the content of outbound messages via a simple search & replace (or regular expression). It should be able to be configured to do this only for emails being sent to addresses that match certain domains.

Specifically, I have an application that sends emails containing URLs. I need to be able to be able to perform a search & replace on those URLs before the email is delivered. I cannot change the application itself, but can point it at an SMTP server of my choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to have your email server deliver the email to a shell script via [Procmail](http://www.procmail.org/). Procmail can run the mail through an arbitrary script (by using a .forward file); the script could then remail the result in whatever form you choose.

A bit hackish (but then any solution would be), but should be easy to implement & test. I've done something similar for automatically processing Return Receipts.

This might actually be cleaner than using an SMTP server, because you are really generating a new mail, rather than messing with an existing mail (which is not really supported by established email handling standars).

Comment: I've decided against attempting to do this now, but I think the procmail route would be the one I'd use if I did. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Spamassassin could probably be modified fairly easily to do this.

Failing that Anomy Sanitizer might be able to do it.

Answer (score 1):

if you use windows platform, I suggest you try [hmail server](http://www.hmailserver.com/). It is free, opensource and has a COM API which allow you to modify the content of emails.